# Convert this line from htaccess to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Can someone help me to rewrite this line from htaccess file to Nginx

```
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)\.api(/(.*))?$ site.php?action=api_$1&arg=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in you location. Eg:

```
location / {
    ....
    rewrite ^/([\w]+)\.api(/(.*))?$ /site.php?action=api_$1&arg=$3 break;
    ....
}
```